# Consulta de fecha actual en Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la columna fecha con el tipo de datos `DATE`; tengo almacenados datos desde `2018-01-01 00:00:00.0` hasta la presente fecha.

Al momento de realizar una consulta desearía saber cómo hago para que me muestre únicamente los datos de la fecha actual.

Si utilizo el `getdate()` no me muestra ningún dato porque busca la fecha y hora del sistema.

Esta es la consulta que tengo:

```
select * from SGT_VIST_PRUEBA where TERMINAL='TTQ' AND FECHA=GETDATE() ORDER BY FECHA DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Debes transformarlo a fecha el getdate() porque por default es datetime, tal cual tu columna, por eso tu columna tienes horas.

```
select * from SGT_VIST_PRUEBA 
where TERMINAL='TTQ' AND FECHA=convert(date,GETDATE()) ORDER BY FECHA DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Solo tienes que convertir la fecha actual a tipo de fecha que quiere ejemplo convirtiendo el getdate() en date solamente para que te traiga solo la fecha, espero que te funcione

```
select * from SGT_VIST_PRUEBA where TERMINAL='TTQ' AND FECHA=CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) ORDER BY FECHA DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Convertí la columna Fecha en formato de fecha corta

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) -- dd/MM/yyyy format
```

Answer (score 0):

Convierte las dos fechas a fecha corta:

```
select * from SGT_VIST_PRUEBA where TERMINAL='TTQ' and convert(varchar(12),FECHA,105)=convert(varchar(12),GETDATE(),105)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando usas la función `GETDATE()` no solo obtienes la fecha también obtienes la hora actual por lo que no tienes ningún registro que corresponda con la hora actual del sistema. La solución sería tomar solamente la fecha al usar `CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())` y filtrar los datos solo con la fecha.

```
SELECT * FROM SGT_VIST_PRUEBA 
WHERE TERMINAL='TTQ' 
AND FECHA = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) 
ORDER BY FECHA DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que ya hay muchas respuestas pero igual presneto mi propuesta:

```
SELECR * 
  FROM SGT_VIST_PRUEBA
 WHERE TERMINAL='TTQ' 
   AND DATEDIFF(day,FECHA,GETDATE())=0
 ORDER BY FECHA DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el metodo NOW(), este toma la fecha actual

```
select * from SGT_VIST_PRUEBA where TERMINAL='TTQ' AND FECHA=NOW() ORDER BY FECHA DESC
```